# need to figure out how to manipulate the mutator to figure out a class according to professor, I am confusd on how to do that

Tags: java

I know we aren't suppose to post homework problems but I am having issues I have talked with him and after 45 minutes I am more confused then I was before he said that this was suppose to be confusing.
So we are working on making our own classes and one of them was making a class to later be used in a weight converter on other planets (mainly the Moon, Mercury, Venus, Jupiter and Saturn) I have managed to make the class (code below)

```
/*
*   WeightConverter class
*   Class Description - A Java class for converting weight on different plants
*   Author: J. Wilson
*   Date:   2/24/2015
*   Filename:   WeightConverter.java
*/


// class beginning
class  WeightConverter {


//create the variable that stores the conversion rate
private double weightchange;

//the constructor
public WeightConverter(double weight){
weightchange=weight;
}
//accessor
public double smallstep(){
return weightchange;
}
//mutator for the needed variable
public void setweightratio(double number){
   weightchange=number;

   }

//and the method convert.
public double convert(double planet){
return planet*weightchange;
}
}
//end of class
```

but he added the stipulation that "In this WeightCalculator class, I expect you to use each method you created at least once.or lose a point for each one your don't use " I asked him how I go about it and after a 45 minute talk i'm more confused then before after he mentioned I can take my mutator and just manipulate that here is what I have currently and it works so far

```
/*
*   WeightConverter on other planets
*   Program Description - weightchanger
*   Author: J.Wilson
*   Date:   2/24/2015
*   Filename:   WeightCalculator.java
*/


//import statements
import java.util.*;     //example

// class beginning
class WeightCalculator {
   public static void main(String[] args ) {
      //Declare variables area

      WeightConverter test;
      Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in );//reads what is entered into the keyboard by the user
      double pounds;
      //Program beginning messages to user here

      System.out.println("Hello! Welcome to my weight converter program");
      System.out.println();//blank space
      System.out.println("Please enter your weight (in pounds): ");
      pounds=scan.nextDouble();
      WeightConverter moon = new WeightConverter(.167);
      System.out.println("Your weight on the moon is " + moon.convert(pounds));


      //Collect inputs from user or read in data here




      //Echo input values back to user here




      //Main calculations and code to



      //Output results here




      //End program message
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Hope you enjoyed using this program!");
       }// end main method


}// end class
```

can anyone explain by what he means by using my mutator more than once? or in laymans terms how to go about doing it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with homework questions in general, it's just that the writers of homework questions often do not follow the guidelines.

Comment: The mutator methods that he is referring to is to use set and get methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should be using setWeightRatio() each time you want to get the weight on a new planet. 
You first created the moon object and set its weight and then later used that set weight in moon.convert()
Next you should setWeightRatio() to a different amount (for Jupiter or Venus or whatever) and that will set the weightChange variable to the new double you just passed in. Then when you use convert() it will access the new weightChange variable and compute based on that.

I would create a single planet object and then reset its weightChange variable through the mutator as necessary. Then use convert() between setting new weight ratio.

Comment: I think that is what he was trying to get across to me the other day as I was talking to him but for some reason I wasn't getting it at all for some reason he was the one that created `WeightConverter moon = new WeightConverter(.167);
      System.out.println("Your weight on the moon is " + moon.convert(pounds));` is it possible you could explain it to me so I can understand it and not have someone write it out for me?

Comment: I would do something like 
    WeightConverter planet = new WeightConverter(.167)
    System.out.println("Your weight on the moon is " + moon.convert(pounds));
then planet.setWeightRatio and add a new planet weight value there. 
when you do that it will then set your weightChange variable to this new value. 
Now when you do moon.convert() again it will use the new value you set (or mutated). So now you can do something like 
system.out.println(Your weight on venus is " + moon.convert(pounds)) and it will return a different value than your moon weight because you mutated a new weight value.

Comment: So I could do
 `WeightConverter moon = new WeightConverter(.167);
      System.out.println("Your weight on the moon is " + moon.convert(pounds));` keep that then on the next line I'd do 
planet.setratio(0.4)
`System.out.println("your weight on Mercury is"+moon.convert())` ?

Comment: You want to use set ratio before you convert again. So after you output that moon weight on the next line make a call to setWeightRatio() with a new value. Then after that do the system.out.println(you weight on venus is convert())
What is happening is inbetween those system.out's you need to change the weight of the weightChange var that you use in the convert method. Once you use setWeightChange that function accesses the weightChange variable and mutates it to a new value so when you use convert() it uses that a new value. You should setWeightRatio before converting each time.

Comment: So if I am getting what you are saying I need to do this 
`WeightConverter moon = new WeightConverter(.167);
      System.out.println("Your weight on the moon is " + moon.convert(pounds));` keep this, on the next line do this?
`weightchange=0.4;`to change the weightchange for it go to Mercury
`System.out.println("your weight on Mercury is"+moon.convert(pounds));`?

Comment: instead of weightchange=0.4 use moon.setWeightRatio(0.4) that way you are utilizing that mutator method. It does the same thing as weightChange = 0.4 but now youre following your professors guidelines and youre getting into encapsulation!

Comment: try 
    moon.setWeightRatio. 
Since setWeightRatio is a function of the moon object you have to input the object a period and then its function like moon.setWeightRatio(0.4)

Comment: okay so I'm implementing what you've taught me but I have ran into this error 

WeightCalculator.java:32: error: cannot find symbol

       moon.setWeightRatio(0.4);
           ^
  symbol:   method setWeightRatio(double)
  location: variable moon of type WeightConverter
1 error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71832/discussion-between-john-park-and-web-cobra).

Answer (score 0):

You professor said that you have to use all the methods in your class at least once, correct?

your `setweightratio` method is useless (this should be obvious, as you havent used it !). it sets the class variable `weightchange` to its input argument, but the same thing happens in the constructor, so you would not need to call it again.

You have two options:

You've already returned moon weight to the user. When the next planet is in question, **keep your WeightConverter instance** and call `moon.setweightratio(ratio of Venus or whatever)`. Using `moon.convert(pounds)` will then use the new ratio.

Alternatively, remove the setweightratio method all together (so you don't get points off for not using it) and create WeightConverter objects for each planet. This is less elegant.